# MySQL JDBC URL Failover with 2 different database names

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-boot, mysql-connector

I would like to have a jdbc url with 2 different schema/database names in `application.yml` in a SpringBoot application.

I tried these out by following [Reference Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) but unfortunately I was not able to get this working.

```
jdbc:mysql://address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=IP1)(port=3306)(user=root)(password=root)/dbname1?failOverReadOnly=false,address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=IP2)(port=3306)(user=test)(password=test)/dbname2?failOverReadOnly=false

jdbc:mysql://address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=IP1)(port=3306)(user=root)(password=root)(dbname=dbname1)?failOverReadOnly=false,address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=IP2)(port=3306)(user=test)(password=test)(dbname=dbname2)?failOverReadOnly=false
```

The error I am receiving is at starting the application because the MySQL connector is not able to parse the url connections string.

```
2017-02-21 11:37:40.724] log4j - 3060 ERROR [main] --- o.a.t.j.p.ConnectionPool: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'failOverReadOnly' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'false,address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(user=test)(password=test)/dbname2?failOverReadOnly=false' is not in this set.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
```

Comment: Were you getting an error?

Comment: I receive the error as I start the server and the connector parses the connections url

Comment: The error message an the code you pasted don't match up.  In your code it says "user=root", and the error says "user=test" (among other differences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, error message is pretty straight forward- `The connection property 'failOverReadOnly' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'false,address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(user=test)(password=test)/dbname2?failOverReadOnly=false' is not in this set.`

Your value of property - `failOverReadOnly` is taken as - `false,address=(type=master)(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(user=test)(password=test)/dbname2?failOverReadOnly=false` instead of simply `false`.

Format -

```
jdbc:mysql://address=(key1=value)[(key2=value)]...[,address=(key3=value)[(key4=value)]...]...[/[database]]»
[?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
```

is specifying to list all `address` first then all properties in the end while you wrote properties just after one address.

All in all, your URLs are not in format mentioned in documentation.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: How do I manage to have propertyName1 referring to address1 but propertyName2 referring to address2 ?

Comment: I guess, there seems some misunderstanding about these properties. These are not address specific properties but overall configuration properties i.e. how your fail over works etc.

Answer (score 3):

Its an old thread, and I don't know if you have got the solution worked out for you.

But I have been in the similar situation and JDBC URL below worked like a charm for me

```
"jdbc:mysql://IP1:port1,IP2:port2/CommonDbName?failOverReadOnly=false"
```

In this situation at any point of time your application will be connected to only one db, which is on IP1, and once this db is down, it will switch to second DB i.e. IP2, and since you have marked `failOverReadOnly` to false, second DB will be active in both read/write mode.

Reference -

**[8.1 Configuring Server Failover](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-config-failover.html)**

Comment: always format your code in your question/answer. Also, put some official document reference (wherever possible) to support your answer